# Networkx: find way according to .dot file attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7, networkx

I'm working with digraph defined in dot language using networkx. I need to achieve something like this:

```
 X = networkx.read_dot('_t.dot')  #loads dotfile
 def navigate_through_model(model, type):  #model is model, type -> string of desired 'comment'
    .....
    return path

 if \__target\__== '\__main\__':
    print navigate_through_model(X, 'regression') # I need to return path, that is going through all nodes with comment == 'regression'  (it can be other attribute, comment is only for question)
```

And I'm kind a lost in this :(

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok I finally gets to this:

```
import networkx
X = networkx.read_dot('_t.dot')

def navigate_through_model(model, start_node, end_node, typex):
    path = []
    actual_node = start_node
    visited_nodes = []
    status = True
    while actual_node != end_node:
        u = networkx.all_neighbors(model, actual_node)
        for line in u:
            target_node = line
            print target_node
            try:
                comm = model[actual_node][target_node][0]['comment']
                if (comm == typex and target_node not in visited_nodes):
                    path.append((actual_node, target_node))
                    actual_node = target_node
                    visited_nodes.append(target_node)
                    print path
                    print '\n'
                    print visited_nodes
                    status = True
                else:
                    status = False
            except Exception as err:
                pass
        if not status:
            return "not found"
    return path

print navigate_through_model(X, 'start', 'end', 'regression')
```

Maybe it is not the best solution but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I found (after good sleep) that I can use weight of edges to achieve the same result.  So solution is easy.. set lowest weight to 'regression' path and than just generate shortest path.

```
networkx(X, 'start', 'end', weight='weight')
```

In order to do this you have to edit networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/weighted.py
There is some kind of bug on the row 342.

```
vw_dist = dist[v] + edgedata.get(weight, 1)
```

You have to change it to:

```
vw_dist = dist[v] + float(edgedata.get(weight, 1))   #if you want to use floating number or just int to use integers
```